# get hidden column value on class click Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to get the hidden cell value when clicked on input box which is inside same row in datatables

Here is my table initialization

```
var oTable1 = jQuery('#sample-table-2').DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [1]
    }],
});

jQuery('.interimRental').click(function () {
    var tre = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var fid = oTable1.fnGetData(tre);
    console.log(fid);
});
```

interimRental is my input box class name which is inside td so  i want that when i click on this input box i should get the hidden column cell value when i try the above code i get error as

> TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `jQuery('#sample-table-2').DataTable` to `jQuery('#sample-table-2').dataTable`, since `fnGetData()` is an older DataTables method and `DataTable()` returns newer API instance. See [API reference](https://datatables.net/manual/api) for more information.

Also, as a side note, use delegated event handler to handle clicks. This is needed because DataTables manipulates table elements and your click handler will stop functioning if not defined as shown below.

```
jQuery('#sample-table-2 tbody').on('click', '.interimRental', function (){
    var tre = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var fid = oTable1.fnGetData(tre);
    console.log(fid);
});
```